# JQuery Replace "Special" Function (like replace(/#[^#]*$/, "") replace(/\?[^\?]*$/, ""))

Tags: jquery, replace

Where i can find all the possible replace like "replace(/#[^#]*$/, "")" and "replace(/\?[^\?]*$/, "")" with their function and examples? Thanks to all.

Comment: there's a near infinite number of different regular expressions that could possibly be used there.

Answer (score 0):

They are called [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

> Regular expressions are patterns used to match character combinations in strings

Answer (score 0):

As said, you're asking about regular expressions commonly called a "regex".  Take a look at [**Regular-Expressions.info**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for tons of good information.  The page you're probably most interested in is the [**Literal Characters and Special Characters**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), which largely answers your OP. A great site to test your regex is [**Rubular.com**](http://www.rubular.com/).  It's designed for Ruby, but works great for nearly anything I've thrown at it (sed expressions, C# replace, JS replace, etc.).

HTH